# How to compute this partial derivative with scalar product?

Tags: derivatives

Let $\langle u,v\rangle =\int_0^1 u(x)v(x)\, dx$.

I would like to compute
$$
L(\langle y(x,t),\Phi(x)\rangle\Phi(x)), \text{ where }~~L=\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}.
$$

My computation gave
$$
L(\langle y(x,t),\Phi(x)\rangle\Phi(x))=\left(\langle Ly,\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\Phi\rangle+2\langle\frac{\partial y}{\partial x},\frac{\partial\Phi}{\partial x}\rangle+\langle y,L\Phi\rangle\right)\Phi+\langle y,\Phi\rangle\frac{\partial\Phi}{\partial x}.
$$

Can anybody tell me if I am right?

Answer (score 0):

I think it is not right. As far as I understand, $ <u,v>$ is not a function of $x$. So $ L (<u,v>)= 0$.

$<y(x,t),\Phi(x)>$ is a function of $t$ only.

Comment: So, you think that $L(\langle y,\Phi\rangle\Phi)=\langle y,\Phi\rangle L\Phi$?

Comment: Yes, I think that $L(⟨y,\Phi⟩\Phi)=⟨y,\Phi⟩L\Phi$.

Comment: Would be my guess, too. My friend says it is $\langle Ly,\Phi\rangle\Phi$.